# Create addon domains from web page

Tags: linux, php, domain, shell

I have a VPS (CentOS) with CPanel and Suphp enabled. 
Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_fcgid/2.3.5

As a root I created an account and set up a domain for it. Now I can login to this account's CPanel and create addon domains. 
For my project I want to allow the visitors of my website to do same thing (create addon domains) from my PHP script.

I'm a PHP developer and I have a very limited Linux administration experience. I can use system() or similar PHP function to call a command file, but what this command file should contain? I believe there must be some user authorization and the necessary stuff to change config files... Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured this out. With CPanel it's very easy actually: it provides the API for administrative tasks. http://etwiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi

But what if I don't have CPanel? Many VPS hosters either don't offer CPanel option or require additional monthly fee for it. What can be done to automate creating addon domains in this case?

Thank you.